# Error "Package 'WindowsAPICodePack 7.0.4' was restored using '.NETFramework..." for a NET6 package

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, .net-standard-2.0, windows-api-code-pack

I have a .NET Standard 2.0 project which depends on another project targeting "net6.0-windows;net48". The other project uses a NET6 WindowsAPICodePack Nuget package.

When I build the solution, the other project builds fine but the depending project gets this error about WindowsAPICodePack being restored for the old .NET Framework.

```
Warning As Error: Package 'WindowsAPICodePack 7.0.4' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
```

[image]

How can I force it to restore the package for .NET6/Standard2.0?

Comment: Just the obvious reason: you can't have a .netstandard project that depends on a library that isn't standard.

Comment: So what should I do? Change the dependent project's target framwork (the project which references WindowsAPICodePack) to .NET Standard 2.0?

Comment: No, that is what you already have, don't you? You need to change the dependent project's target framework (the project which references the WindowsAPICodePack) to a TFM that WindowsAPICodePack [supports](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAPICodePack#dependencies-body-tab).

Comment: The project referencing WindowsAPICodePack targets .NET6. I see WindowsAPICodePack supports .NET6: https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAPICodePack#supportedframeworks-body-tab